# Medicare Claiming / EasyClaim

Tags: java, api

I am trying to integrate Medicare Australia Easyclaim API. But there is no proper documentation for this API.
They are trying to create XML request using this method.
Is there such type of recommendation or RFCs to define XML in this way ?

```
EasyclaimAPI.getInstance().createBusinessObject(sessionId, "HIC/HolClassic/Dbs@1", "", "", result);
```

Please help me.
Thanks in  advance.

Comment: Please provide links to the software for the API you are talking about.

Comment: @Stephen This is not a public API. Please see this link.
https://www.humanservices.gov.au/health-professionals/subjects/getting-started-software-vendor

Comment: I don't think you are going to get a meaningful answer to this Question here.  This is a private AP with zero public information available.  The number of people who know much about it will be very small.  (I'm guessing maybe less than 20 world-wide)  There is minimal chance that any of them are regular StackOverflow answers.  Sorry.  You should be using the established support channel.

Comment: Thanks @Stephen, But this is very strange. They are not providing any developer level technical support, they only let you know things are correctly submitted to their server or not. So I am looking for such person who has experience about this API.

Comment: The link you provided says, and I quote, "The first point of contact for new Software Vendors is the Online Technical Support Liaison team who can provide advice on what's required to commence your development and integration with any of the eHealth channels.  Online Technical Support Liaison contact details can be found on [Health Professionals contact information](https://www.humanservices.gov.au/health-professionals/contact-us#ots)." That is where your question should be addressed. Not here. Off topic.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there such type of recommendation or RFCs to define XML in this way ?

If such "recommendations" or "RFCs" existed then the people who would know about them would be the "Online Technical Support Liaison team" mentioned in the page you linked to.

Or to put it another way, if there are "recommendations or RFCs" that might be applicable but the Liason team cannot point you to them, the chances are that the API's you are trying to use don't *conform* to them ... which would make them irrelevant.

RFCs (in particular the [IETF RFCs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request_for_Comments)) are about public Internet standards.  Private APIs and protocols are outside of the scope of the IETF.

Answer (score 0):

from your link provide I dug in deep.
You'll need to get these documents:
[ATS 5821-2010](http://infostore.saiglobal.com/store/Details.aspx?ProductID=1391034)
[ATS 5820-2010](http://infostore.saiglobal.com/store/Details.aspx?ProductID=1391033)

I found them here: http://www.e-health.standards.org.au/Home/Publications.aspx
From here: https://www.humanservices.gov.au/health-professionals/services/medicare/healthcare-identifiers-service-software-developers